# How to paint on model

Tags: texture-painting, artifacts

I want to paint onto my model but artifacts keep appearing.

Answer (score 1):

You have inner faces that go outside, select them and scale down:

[image]

The unwrap is bad, some big faces of your object are tiny in the *UV Editor* and vice-versa. You need to *Unwrap > Reset*. Your object is made of two meshes, so select a face of the bottom part, then select the whole bottom *Unwrap > Follow Active Quads*. Do the same for the top part. You'll get something like that:

[image]

Comment: actually you need to select the outer faces as these are the ones that should be the inner faces  ;)

Comment: the inner faces cross the outer ones, so you need to fix that a way or another, it should not change the shape a lot

Comment: press Alt Z to have transparency, you need to select and scale down the bottom edge loops to avoid inner faces going through outer faces. If you're a bit lost you can also delete these faces and redo the bottom